# Make fancy border in inkscape and gimp

Tags: inkscape, gimp, borders

I relatively new to GIMP and inkscape and trying to build posters but i couldn't find a any video or forum posts in which people create custom border images and use them as border (either they add solid color as border or just give rounded corner)

So my question is if I have an image how can use it as a border with style like rounded edge or triangle etc ?

[image: example image]

Comment: one important question first, do you know how to create a rounded rectangle using the rectangle tool?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. I would say you cut out the inner part of your image, such that the border remains, and put it (probably as a separate layer) above your content, but maybe your problem is something else.

Comment: no as i said i am starting out new is can you suggest some videos or links @fred_dot_u

Comment: yeah i tried that technique but what i want is to create a custom design or use a image as a border

Comment: @VishnuEzhuthachan I see you reversed the edits that I made to your question, and as it is YOUR question I respect your decision to do so. But I'm curious to know why, as I felt like they improved the quality of the question.

Comment: @RoobyDooby I acknowledge and thank you for correcting me.  Please do not take it personally. I used that heading specifically so that the question won't be ignored as a noob question

Answer (score 1):

This is for Inkscape.

1. Using the Rectangle Tool <kbd>F4</kbd>, draw two rectangles, one inside the other, and fill each with a different colour by selecting a different fill colour. The colours don't matter, so long as you can see both rectangles clearly

[image]

2. With the Select Object tool <kbd>F1</kbd>. Select both shapes by clicking and dragging the tool around both, and align them horizontally and vertically using the Align tools in the Align and Distribute panel <kbd>Shfit</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to make sure everything is centred

[image]

3. Using the Rectangle Tool, click and drag the top right corner widget to round the corners of the inner rectangle

[image]

4. Select both shapes and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (Difference). This will cut out the top shape from the bottom leaving a hole.
5. Copy paste or Import an image, and send it to the bottom of the stack by hitting <kbd>End</kbd> (send to bottom)
6. With the Select Object tool <kbd>F1</kbd>, click and drag it to move it under the border you made.

[image]

7. If necessary rescale the image by clicking and dragging the corner handles
8. Once in position, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all), then do *Object > Clip > Set* . This will make a clipping mask - which basically means the image is clipped inside the border you made previously.

[image]

9. Note that the inside of the clipped image is a transparent hole, which means you can place another image underneath it.

[image]

Comment: other than for differentiation, is it necessary to fill the two rectangles with color?

Comment: thanks any way for GIMP ? @Billy Kerr

Comment: @fred_dot_u No. It's just so you can see them. I mentioned this in the tutorial.

Comment: @VishnuEzhuthachan Yes, it could be done in GIMP with a layer mask, but this took me long enough to write. Perhaps someone else can tackle that.

Comment: please if possible putting up some youtube links would help @billy Kerr

Comment: @VishnuEzhuthachan Just google "layer masking tutorial in GIMP" - once you've learnt the basics, you should be able to apply the skills to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

For GIMP as @Billy Kerr said layer masking is used

1. Select any image to be set as border
2. Add a new layer above it (FG or BG color or white but not transparent)
3. On the newly add layer right click add new layer mask (select the option and find which one suits you)
4. using selection tool select the amount of area you want empty
5. invert selection and fill with black color

visual reference of the above :
https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/

Answer (score 0):

For Inkscape, another option would be to:

1. Draw the frame object in whichever way you want. It could just be a wide stroke on a rectangle, or you draw some complex shape, whichever is useful to you.
2. Import the image and embed it.
3. Select the image, then convert it to a pattern (Object > Object to Pattern)
4. Apply this pattern to either the stroke or the fill of your frame object
5. Use the node tool to adjust the pattern handles, and with them the size, position and rotation of the image.